# WindowsService don´t execute while

Tags: c#, while-loop, windows-services

I'm doing a small windows service, it reads from a web service and stores the data in a local database, however, it does not finish executing the while (while it's a service), when I'm debugging it in vs 15 it works perfectly , Follow the code below.

PS: The code I used to debug I comment it before it starts, it arrives to enter the while, but only the first line and does not check the rest.

**Program.cs**

```
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace rdi_server.service
{
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
}
```

**Service1.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

namespace rdi_server.service
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{

    private Thread _thread;

    private Updater _updater = new Updater();

    private readonly int Interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["timer"]);
    private readonly string Connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection"];

    private readonly Connector _usuarioConnector;
    private readonly Connector _bandaConnector;
    private readonly Connector _generoConnector;
    private readonly Connector _musicaConnector;

    public Service1()
    {
        _usuarioConnector = new Connector("UsuarioBase");
        _bandaConnector = new Connector("BandaBase");
        _generoConnector = new Connector("GeneroBase");
        _musicaConnector = new Connector("MusicaBase");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        StartDebug();
    }

    public void StartDebug()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(OnTime);
        _thread.Name = "My Worker Thread";
        _thread.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    protected void OnTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Dentro do WHILE foi executado!");
            _updater.Do(Connection, _usuarioConnector, _generoConnector, _bandaConnector, _musicaConnector);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Fim do while");
            Thread.Sleep(Interval);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Updater.CS**

```
using rdi_musica.core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace rdi_server.service
    {
    class Updater
    {
    public void Do(string Connection,
                        Connector usuario,
                        Connector genero,
                        Connector banda,
                        Connector musica)
    {

        var usuarios = Loader.LoadUsuarios(usuario);
        var generos = Loader.LoadGeneros(genero);
        var bandas = Loader.LoadBandas(banda);
        var musicas = Loader.LoadMusicas(musica);


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            foreach (var _usuario in usuarios)
            {
                DomainDAO.InsertUsuario(connection, _usuario);
            }
            foreach (var _genero in generos)
            {
                DomainDAO.InsertGenero(connection, _genero);
            }
            foreach (var _banda in bandas)
            {
                DomainDAO.InsertBanda(connection, _banda);
            }
            foreach (var _musica in musicas)
            {
                DomainDAO.InsertMusica(connection, _musica);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider writing a [mcve] including the code (here, not a link) so this question can have relevance in the future if links go dead.

Comment: Is your code throwing some kind of exception?

Comment: Re: the first comment, I'll go one further: you _must_ provide a good [mcve] if you expect help here. Not only does doing so prevent your question from becoming unusuable, it ensures that you have provided exactly the information required to answer your question, no less and no more. See also [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Have you created an event sync on the remote machine for the event log you are writing? Can you write to the log on that machine? I would take the first line of the while loop's logic and place that into a tester application and see if you can reproduce the error outside of the windows service.

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is you have an unhandled exception happening somewhere, which is breaking out of your while loop.

You can use the windows event log in combination with try-catch to log your errors, without breaking your infinite loop:

```
protected void OnTime()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Dentro do WHILE foi executado!");
            _updater.Do(Connection, _usuarioConnector, _generoConnector, _bandaConnector, _musicaConnector);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Fim do while");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.EventLog.WriteEntry("ERROR: " + ex.GetType().ToString() + " : " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(Interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I did this and nothing, but what makes me abstain is that when I'm debugging it it works perfectly, connects to web services, retrieves the information and writes to the database